# Can't get the categories to show

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working off the TwentyTwelve theme and I have modified the index file by adding this snippet before the loop

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main" class="clearfix">
        <?php
             $terms = get_the_category();
             $count = count($terms);
             echo '<ul id="post-filter">';
                echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';
                if ( $count > 0 ){

                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                        $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                        $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                        echo '<li><a href="#'.$termname.'" title="" rel="'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
                    }
             }
             echo "</ul>";
        ?>
        <div id="mwrapper">

    <?php query_posts('cat=-6,-7'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="box">....
```

I'm trying to create a filter that will filter through the blog post. Like the demo [here](http://www.wpthemetoolset.com/filterable/#all). Currently I have five categories: Agency Notes, Design Notes, Featured, Humor, Uncategorized. And there's at least one post per category but it seems to be pulling in Design Notes only.

I have also tried changing the `get_the_category();` to `wp_list_categories();` but that ended up showing all the categories.

[Source](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-wordpress-and-jquery/?search_index=5) I'm getting the snippet from.

Comment: first off, it's better to use `$term->slug` instead of `strtolower()` and `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 2):

`get_the_category()` grabs the current post's category/ies information, not the list of categories in the full WP installation.

I think what you're looking for is the `get_categories()` function (more info here at the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

```
<?php
     $categories=get_categories( array( 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'name' ) );
     $count = count($terms);
     [...]
```

Comment: also probably need the `query_posts()` before, not after it, as in the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you want to get all categories. get_the_category() does not do this. You probably want get_categories() instead.

```
$terms = get_categories();
$count = count($terms);
echo '<ul id="post-filter">';
  echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';
  if ( $count > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      echo '<li><a href="#" data-slug="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
    }
  }
echo "</ul>";
```

I also made a few modifications: removed the hash and rel attribute. We can use data-attributes instead, which are more semantic.

The next part depends on your post HTML, but I'm assuming they have a class of `post` and the category they're in. If they do, you can do something like this with jQuery:

```
$('a', '#post-filter').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.post').hide().filter('.' + $(this).attr('data-slug')).show();
});
```

Which will hide all posts, and only show the ones in the selected category. I'll leave it to you to sort out the animations.